# I don't want each card with same height....i wanna put 2 more cards following two small cards but don't know how to do it

Tags: css

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9DQz.jpg)
I don't want each card with same height....i wanna put 2 more cards following two small cards but don't know how to do it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
  <title>Shelby News</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: lightcyan">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="card bg-inverse card-bg-zoom">
          <img class="card-img" src="images/business.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
          <div class="card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end overlay">
            <h4 class="card-title">
              SOME SAMPLE TEXT FOR CARD Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere eos eveniet, cupiditate
              modi similique suscipit
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="card bg-inverse card-bg-zoom">
          <img class="card-img" src="images/business.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
          <div class="card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end overlay">
            <h4 class="card-title">SOME SAMPLE TEXT FOR CARD</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="card bg-inverse card-bg-zoom">
          <img class="card-img" src="images/business.jpg" alt="Card image cap" />
          <div class="card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end overlay">
            <h4 class="card-title">SOME SAMPLE TEXT FOR CARD</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

i wanna put 2 more cards following two small cards but don't know how to do it.i'm using bootstrap row and col classes as well as i want this to be responsive,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
  <title>Shelby News</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: lightcyan">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
        <div class="card bg-inverse card-bg-zoom">
          <img class="card-img" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=611"  alt="Card image cap" />
          <div class="card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end overlay">
            <h4 class="card-title">
              SOME SAMPLE TEXT FOR CARD Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere eos eveniet, cupiditate
              modi similique suscipit
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="card bg-inverse card-bg-zoom" style="margin-bottom:12px">
          <img class="card-img" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=611"  alt="Card image cap" />
          <div class="card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end overlay">
            <h4 class="card-title">SOME SAMPLE TEXT FOR CARD</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="card bg-inverse card-bg-zoom">
          <img class="card-img" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=611"  alt="Card image cap" />
          <div class="card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end overlay">
            <h4 class="card-title">SOME SAMPLE TEXT FOR CARD</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="card bg-inverse card-bg-zoom" style="margin-bottom:12px">
          <img class="card-img" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=611"  alt="Card image cap" />
          <div class="card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end overlay">
            <h4 class="card-title">SOME SAMPLE TEXT FOR CARD</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="card bg-inverse card-bg-zoom">
          <img class="card-img" src="https://picsum.photos/300/200?image=611"  alt="Card image cap" />
          <div class="card-img-overlay h-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-end overlay">
            <h4 class="card-title">SOME SAMPLE TEXT FOR CARD</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</html>
```